# Solving Bitwise Equation

Tags: algorithm, binary, bit-manipulation, bit

I have a bitwise equation of the form

> `X = (A & X) + (B & X)`

where `A and B` are known integers and `X` is unknown, How do I find X?
Here, `&` is Bitwise AND and `+` is Arithmetic addition, A, B, and X are integers.

One of the trivial solutions is zero but I have to return that if no other solution is possible.

My approach: I know the range of X so I could iterate over it in O(n) to check for the condition but the range could be very large so it might not be efficient.

Also, I tried doing `AND` operations on both sides to shorten the equation but cannot come to a meaningful solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's begin by focusing on just one bit of X, the very last bit. It can be either 0 or 1, and depending on how A and B are structured, we may be able to rule certain options out. There are four combinations of the last bits of A and B, but there's really only three cases to consider because of symmetry:

- Case 1: A and B end in zero. In that case, `A & X` ends in 0 and `B & X` ends in 0. Therefore, since `X` = `A & X` + `B & X`, the last bit of `X` must be 0.
- Case 2: One of A and B ends in 1 and the other ends in 0. Assume, without loss of generality, that `A` ends in 1 and `B` ends in 0. Then `A & X` + `B & X` = 0 + `X` = `X`, so either choice of bit for the last bit of `X` works.
- Case 3: A and B end in 1. In that case, `A & X` ends with the last bit of X and `B & X` ends with the last bit of X. Then the last bit of X is given by `A & X` + `B & X` = `X` + `X` = 2`X` = 0, since multiplying any bit by two and looking at the lowest resulting bit gives 0.

Stated differently, in each case for the combination of `A` and `B` bits, we can determine what bit(s) are possible for `X` by consulting a table and then move one position to the right to process the next bit. The table, specifically, is shown here

```
 A | B | X
---+---+---
 0 | 0 | 0
 0 | 1 | any
 1 | 0 | any
 1 | 1 | 0
```

Note that this matches your intuition that zero is always a solution, since these rules allow you to pick 0 for any bit that you'd like. But if you'd like to find a solution that isn't 0 everywhere, just fill in 1s any time you have a choice.

As an example, suppose `A` in binary is `011101001` and `B` in binary is `001101010`. Then, using this table, we have these options:

```
    A 011101001
    B 001101010
    X 0*00000*0
```

That gives four possibilities:

```
010000010
010000000
000000010
000000000
```

And we can check that, indeed, each of these is a solution to `X` = `A & X` + `B & X`.

This solution runs in time O(b), where b is the number of bits in the numbers A and B. That's O(log A + log B), if you're given A and B numerically, which means that this is *way* faster than a brute-force search.

Hope this helps!